# Local Inverse Function Theorem consequence

Tags: analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R} }$
The theorem states:

"Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \R^n$ be a $C^r$-map defined on the open set $\Omega$ of $\R^n$.
If the differential $df_p:\R^n \rightarrow \R^n$ of $f$ in $p \in \Omega$ is an isomorphism, then there exist neighborhoods $U \ni p$ and $V \ni f(p)$ such that $f|_U:U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^r$-diffeomorphism."

Well, I'm trying to proof that, if $f:\R^n \rightarrow \R^n$ is $C^1$ and $y \in \R^n$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a discrete set.

The author of the question simply says "By the Local Inverse Function Theorem, each point of $f^{-1}(y)$ is isolated", that is, for each $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ there exist a neighborhood $V \ni x$ such that $V \cap f^{-1}(y) = \{x \}$, and I really don't know how it works.

Can someone explain me this statement with details, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $r,s \in f^{-1}(y)$ and you know have $r,s \in U$ where $f|_U: U \to V$ is a diffeomorphism then this is a contradiction since $f|_U$ is injective but $f(r) = f(s) = y$. Therefore, the points in $f^{-1}(y)$ must be isolated.

The above answer is a bit sloppy, let me try again;

If you know $r,s \in f^{-1}(y)$ and for any neighborhood $U_r$, we have $s \in U_r$. Then for the open set $U$ in which $d_rf$ is an isomorphism,we have that since $U$ is a neighborhood of $r$ then $s \in U$. However, $f|_{U}$ is a diffeomorphism (in particular injective), but clearly $f(r) = f(s) = y$ which is a contradiction.

Now this aligns with the Inverse Function Theorem since it says that; if $d_xf$ is an isomorphism, then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ for which $f|_U$ is a diffeomorphism. Now since you $r,s \in f^{-1}(y)$ are isolated then you can get a neighborhood $U_r$ s.t $s \not \in U_r$, i.e injectivity is possible.